# a href value does not pass to next php link

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe, hyperlink

i am using datatables with iframe `(iframe parent page -> icontent.php -> var.php)` populating the table works fine but i cannot seem to pass the variable to the other page `(var.php)`, I have this code on my php page `(icontent.php)`

```
<?php 
   while ($row=$ result->fetch_row()){ 
       $array = array($row[0], $row[1]); 
       $arraytemp = serialize($array); 
?>
<tr>
  <td>
    <?=$row[0]?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php 
        echo "<a href=\"../variety.php?array=$ arraytemp\ ">$row[1]</a>";
    ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?=$row[2]?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php 
        if(!is_null($row[3]))echo $row[3]; else echo 0;
    ?>
  </td>

  <?php 
      echo " <td><a href=\"updateprice.html\ " class=\"btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-sm btn-block btn-block\ ">Update Market Price</a>
                                            <a href=\"updatebatchspoilage.html\ " class=\"btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-sm btn-block btn-block\ ">Manage Spoilage</a></td>"; 
  ?>
  <tr>
<?php } ?>
```

but once i click the row link on the table i get this error `"Notice: Undefined index: array in C:\xampp\htdocs\introse\views\variety.php on line 46"`

with this code on the other page (`var.php`)

```
<?php 
   session_start(); 
   $tarray=$ _GET[ 'array']; 
   $tarray=unserialize($tarray); 
   echo $array[0]; 
?>
```

Comment: That would be because you call it `$tarray` then try to access it via `$array`..

Comment: I think the problem is on line 46.

Comment: is the GET parameter based on the variable name or the "variable" after the ? in the a href link

Comment: i also tried to enclose $arraytemp like '.$arraytemp.'

Comment: i made the changes, var.php to variety and icontent to inventory and after clicking the link to variety.php it switches pages but the address remains the same as when im in inventory.php

Comment: You said it's in an iframe, right? The address bar shows the parent window's address. Not the iframe's address.

Answer (score 0):

See this line right here:

```
echo "<a href=\"../variety.php?array=$ arraytemp\ ">$row[1]</a>";
```

I don't think you need that space after the `$`.

Also, you got another one here:

```
$tarray=$ _GET[ 'array'];
```

Comment: the insertion of the code somehow  messed up the spacing, my actual code does not have any space in those portions

Comment: OK, then you also need to run `$arraytemp` through `htmlspecialchars()` because it probably contains some `"` which will break your html. Open the page in the browser and view the html source, the link is broken, right?

Comment: now that youve mentioned that, the link remains "http://localhost/introse/views/inventory.php" even after the value passed

Comment: inventory.php? You're looking in entirely the wrong place. The link is variety.php.

Comment: i made the changes, var.php to variety and icontent to inventory and after clicking the link to variety.php it switches pages but the address remains the same as when im in inventory.php

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
   session_start(); 
   $tarray=$ _GET[ 'array']; 
   $tarray=unserialize($tarray); 
   echo $tarray[0]; 
?>
```